# Exporting Flow type in CommonJS?

Tags: flowtype, commonjs

Is it possible to export and import Flow type definitions in CommonJS world similarly to [ES6 like type imports/exports](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/#toc-importing-and-exporting-values)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no CommonJS-style `require` for Flow, but Flow's `import type`/`export type` syntax can be used alongside CommonJS `require` calls.

Though the syntax looks similar, `import type` and `export type` are not actual JavaScript `import`/`export` statements. They must be stripped from your code before your code can be run in current browsers. If you use Babel to compile your code, for example, you use the [transform-flow-strip-types](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/) plugin to strip Flow types and type imports/exports.