# How can I export a flow interfaces using CommonJS?

Tags: flowtype

I'm not sure if my build is good or not, but in my `package.json`, I have

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "flow-remove-types src/ -d build/",
```

And I have a `types/sentence.js`, which has:

```
// @flow

type SentenceObject = {
  foo: number,
  bar: boolean,
  baz: string,
};

module.exports = {
  SentenceObject
};
```

And in my library file, I have:

```
const { SentenceObject } = require('../interfaces/sentence');
```

The problem, when I do `yarn build` is:

```
src/interfaces/sentence.js
 ↳ Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected = (3:27)
   2:  export type SentenceObject {
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to [no CommonJS style for require flow types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48410897/exporting-flow-type-in-commonjs). Instead you can use `export`/`import` [as suggested in docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/). So in your case it might be something like:

`types/sentence.js`:

```
// @flow
export type SentenceObject = {
  foo: number,
  bar: boolean,
  baz: string,
};
```

notice the `export` keyword.

And in your library file you can use `import type {...} from ''`:

```
import type { SentenceObject } from '../interfaces/sentence';
```